# H2 DB - How to disable full group by

Tags: sql, h2

There is a flag in mysql which enable/disable full group by (ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) But I am searching for same flag or connection string param to disable full group by in H2 database.

Here is my sample data.

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | SYNC_ID       | LIFECYCLE_EVENT |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 3  | 41            | 2               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 41            | 1               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 4  | 69            | 1               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 5  | 69            | 3               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

Here is my desired output:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | SYNC_ID       | LIFECYCLE_EVENT |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 3  | 41            | 2               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 5  | 69            | 3               |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

And Here is my query which I am trying to use for desired output

```
select   id, sync_id, max(lifecycle_event)
from asset
where asset_type = 1
GROUP BY sync_id;
```

But it gives me ErrorCode: 90016 which means all non aggregate columns should be selected in group by. If I do so I get the wrong data results.

So Clearly I do not want to group by on id and sync_id . Please guide me how can I achieve this in H2 database.

Comment: There is no such thing.  The flag in MySQL is to avoid the problems with the broken-ness of the old way that MySQL supported `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Rather than trying to convince H2 to return random results, you should fix your query. Even MySQL turns that off by now in newer versions.

Comment: I know that. So H2 database is not fetching the desired results. Is there any other way, because I want the max lifecycle event based on syncId

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have provided the dataset and desired output, So I need to fetch as per my desired output. Can you help in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in almost any other database -- because `group by` is not broken in those databases.  You can phrase the query like this:

```
select a.*
from asset a
where asset_type = 1 and
      lifecycle_event = (select max(lifecycle_event) from asset a2 where a2.sync_id = a.sync_id);
```

Comment: Your solution working fine as well the solution of a_horse_with_no_name . You are using inner query while he is self join. What I know is join always better than inner queries. There are millions of records. So If you can shed some light that which is better way. Thanks.

Comment: @Mubasher . . . What you "know" is simply false.  Often they are equivalent, sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other.  In this case, this is probably the fastest method with an index on `asset(sync_id, lifecycle_event)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below -

```
select max(id),sync_id, max(lifecycle_event)
from asset
where asset_type = 1
GROUP BY sync_id
```

Comment: This is incorrect, it will return the wrong ID if the max lifecycle_event doesn't belong to the highest ID. https://rextester.com/RYQGE10986

Comment: Yes There are data present where max life cycle event inserted before its lower ranked life cycle event i.e. there is data presents where life cycle event 2 comes before life cycle event 1 and max id will be for life-cycle event 1

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point in trying to emulate MySQL's broken `group by` implementation.

You can rewrite your query to

```
select a1.id, a1.sync_id, a2.max_even
from asset a1
  join (
    select sync_id,  max(lifecycle_event) as max_event
    from asset 
    group by sync_id
  ) a2 on a2.sync_id = a1.sync_id
      and a2.max_event = a1.lifecycle_event;
```

Comment: Will self join slow down the query as there are millions of record in this table ?

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will know. Typically it will not - at least not compared with other correct solutions (don't compare it with the broken one)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name , This solution is also working but I am using the Gordon Linoff Solution.